# Can we fire two events on a single check box click one from javascript and other from codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

```
<asp:checkbox ID="chkheader" runat="server" onchangeclicked="checkbox clicked">
<asp:checkbox ID="chkrows" runat="server" onchangeclicked="checkbox clicked">


($document.ready(function(){
 $('#gridview1').find(input:checkbox[id$="chkAll"]).click(function(){

-----do something
}
```

Codebehind

```
protected void checkbox clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
----do something
}
```

I need both events to fire on checkbox click. Is it possible??

Comment: In a way, yes, but they will happen at different times. The JS event will appear to happen immediately, and the .net event will happen during the 'page transition'

Comment: Can i have sample code for this.Only js event is fired for me....

Comment: Ah, you'll need to set AutoPostBack to true:     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />

Comment: What are you doing in the javascript function? A postback will overwrite any changes you have made to the DOM anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! But they JS event will happen, then the postback will occur, then the .net event will happen.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onclick="alert('ohyeh');" />
```

and codebehind, in vb >:)

```
Protected Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    MsgBox("shazam")
End Sub
```